# Why is sparsity useful in dictionary learning?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, dictionaries, sparse-matrices

What is the particular reason for which we use sparse matrix X in dictionary learning equation Y=DX where Y is the signal matrix, D is dictionary and X is the coefficient matrix?

Comment: Since the dictionary *is* sparse.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus No, the dictionary is not sparse. But the X matrix is sparse.

Comment: Right, the dictionary used in a particular document is sparse, and we can use it to our advantage.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What are the advantages of dictionary being sparse? Can you please tell me? That might be helpful.

Comment: Using sparsity, you can recover the dictionary from fewer samples.

Comment: You can look up sparse dictionary learning and compressed sensing on Wikipedia.